# Unable to toggle k-th bit to 1

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

[image]

```
// assembly
    .globl _sqrt2
    _sqrt2:
        movl $0, %eax   # place your code for Q3 here
        movq $16, %rcx
        movq $0x10000, %rdx
    loop:
        cmpq $0, %rcx
        jle end
        xorl %eax, %edx
        movl %eax, %esi
        imull %esi, %esi
        cmpq %rdi, %rsi
        jle continue
        xor %eax, %edx
    continue:
        dec %rcx
        shrq $1, %rdx
        jmp loop

    end:
        ret
```

```c
//main.c
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int sqrt2(unsigned int);

void main () {
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        printf("The integer square root of %u is %u.\n", i, sqrt2(i));
    }
    return;
}
```

Result:

```
The integer square root of 4 is 0.
The integer square root of 5 is 0.
The integer square root of 6 is 0.
The integer square root of 7 is 0.
The integer square root of 8 is 0.
The integer square root of 9 is 0.
```

I am trying to translate this algorithm to assembly, but I think the bit-toggling part doesn't work. `xorl %eax, %edx` is supposed to set the k-th bit to 1, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the k-th bit to 1, you are setting the k+1-st bit to 1. Change `movq $0x10000, %rdx` to `movq $0x8000, %rdx`.

Comment: If I'm reading the OP's code right, EAX stays zero the whole time, never used as a destination after zeroing.  I think they mixed up AT&T `op src, dst` with Intel syntax for some but not all instructions.  And BTW, `btc %reg, %reg` flips bit `k` so you could use a counter instead of a shift.  But shift and xor is probably faster.

Comment: I wrote the whole assembly code. Only given the pseudocode. It's just that the code is not running. After changing to movq $0x8000, %rdx, I got The integer square root of 4 is 49152. for everything

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks, it turns out "xor %eax, %edx" isn't correct, it should be "xor %edx, %eax". Now it's working

Comment: @JoshuaLeung: If you single-step through your code with a debugger, seeing that EAX isn't changing when EDX is non-zero should be a big clue that you got the operands backwards.